# Multiple devs working with a forked repository locally

Tags: git

I have forked a github repository on my online account. I've also cloned it locally. It's currently set up with origin pointing to the forked repo and upstream pointing to the original repo.
I am also working with other devs offline that don't have access to the original repo. They only can see my local forked repo. Is there any easy way to set up the forked repo locally so that the devs can work against it and still be able to push it to origin successfully?

Clarification:
The devs don't have access to the forked github repo. They only have access to its local clone. I want the devs to work with that clone and still commit to it and be able to review the commits before pushing it over to the remote forked repo.

Comment: The concept of "fork" is not a Git concept, it is a Github concept. So, if your coworkers do not have Github access, they cannot "fork" a Git repository. The can still *clone* your local repository provided you give them access.

Comment: Hi @j6t. Thanks for the comment. I've added a clarification to my original post. Given the locally clone repo, does it have to be set up with specific configurations for the devs to be able to clone it to their own workspace and still contribute to it before pushing those changes to the remote repo?

Comment: You have Github repo G. You clone G locally to a repo C. And then the devs clone C to their repos D1, D2, etc. The local C does not have to have a special setup to be clonable (it can be bare or have a worktree although I would recommend the former). It is still unclear for me where you expect your devs to push to, because they cannot access G. They could push to C if you grant them write access (that *is* a special setup). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

(note: I'm not sure I entirely understood your setup : I will assume the other devs can access the forked repo on github, and just don't have the credentials to access the original repo)

The work they push to `forked` can already by pushed and mereged into `upstream`.

Just make sure that you regularly update `forked` with the content of `upstream` if they need to know how `upstream` evolved.

Comment: Hello @LeGEC. Thank you for your answer. I've added a clarification to the original post, hope that clarifies further the restrictions we have over here.